# Number with 0 on the front?

Tags: php, function, math

I have function

```
$x = 012; 
echo $x / 3;
```

Why the result is 3.33333?

But if I use:

```
$x = '012';
```

Then is right. The question is how can this be explained?

Comment: [RTFM](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.integer.php) ;)

Comment: 012 is octal representation in PHP

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Numbers prefixed with 0 are treated as octal numbers:

```
$x = 012;//$x is 10
```

[Details here](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.integer.php)

The reason that `$x = '012';` works is because PHP converts that to an integer without treating it as an octal number.

Answer (score 2):

Numbers with zero are octal numbers. So 012 is an octal number.

From the [PHP manual](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.integer.php):

```
$a = 0123; // octal number (equivalent to 83 decimal)
```